# How to find groups in text with a separator

Tags: c#, regex, string, character

I have the following text

`"a|mother" "b|father"`

I want to find via Regex, groups of text that starts with `'"'` and ends with `'"'` and separate with `'|'` without spaces. Meaning the results would be:

1. `"a|mother"`
2. `"b|father"`

How can I find the |? and how can I find my pattern without spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
  String source = "\"a|mother\" \"b|father\"";

  var result = Regex
    .Matches(source, "\"[^\"]*[^ ]\\|[^ ][^\"]*\"")
    .OfType<Match>();

  Console.Write(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

Output is

```
"a|mother"
"b|father"
```